# Is there a way to acquire metadata about an Amazon RDS database instance using only SQL?

Tags: amazon-rds, sql

For example, if I have a SQL Server instance in RDS, and I have only a connection string to connect to the server, is there a sproc or some pre-configured tables I can access via SQL on the instance that would report the instance size string? (db.r5.xlarge)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a SQL Server on AWS to check, but you could see if it's in [xp_msver](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-msver-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), or figure it out from `ProcessorCount`, `ProcessorType` and `PhysicalMemory` in that sproc.